# Find a set of orthogonal vectors which are still orthogonal under an operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real inner-product space and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Prove that there exists a nonzero orthogonal list $(v_1,v_2,\dots, v_n)$ such that $(Tv_1, Tv_2, \dots, Tv_n)$ is still orthogonal (not necessarily nonzero).

It's not so clear to me that this should even be true. I know for sure that if $T$ is an orthogonal operator, then it will preserve orthogonality, but I'm not sure how we can find such a set of vectors for an arbitrary operator. It also seems immediate if $T$ is invertible. The only idea I have is to decompose $V$ into a direct sum of the image of $T$ and the kernel of $T$. The vectors which are mapped to 0 will remain orthogonal to the rest.

Comment: $$ T = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$   or, now that I think of it, $$ T_2 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: You are not simply finding such a $T$ that works. The problem is given any $T$ find s suitable set of vectors

Comment: no, these are $T$ that do not work. Your question is wrong

Comment: Hint (assuming $T:V\to V$): Consider the eigenvectors of $S=A^*A=A^TA$.

Comment: strange. this was a qualifying exam problem. perhaps that is the reason no one could solve it. I don't quite understand how your examples disprove the statement. How can you know that no such set of vectors exists?

Comment: in fact, using Tai's suggestion the SVD of T gives us $V  = \begin{bmatrix} 1/\sqrt2 & -1/\sqrt{2}\\ 1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2} \end{bmatrix}$. The image of the columns is orthogonal.

Comment: Imp, if you  take your SVD example and then write $TV$  you find one column zero. Now, this would fit what was asked if the phrase " such that $(Tv_1, Tv_2, \dots, Tv_n)$ is still orthogonal "  is interpreted to mean that the zero  vector is allowed, in contrast to "a nonzero orthogonal list"   You have not given a source.

Comment: I can see how that was confusing. Only the set of $v_i$'s must be nonzero. The set of the $Tv_i$'s need only be orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ and write $A = U\Sigma V^\top$ as the singular value decomposition. Then, $AV = U\Sigma V^\top V = U\Sigma$, so the $n$ orthogonal vectors in the columns of $V$ map to some scaling of the $n$ orthogonal vectors in the columns of $U$.

Comment: The question is wrong.

Comment: oh this is clever i think this might be the solution actually